# Laravel existing Project to NGINX Server "Permission denied" 404 Browser error

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

I have setup an new LEMP Server with Nginx and Laravel. All correct setup and 2 fresh default laravel projects run great. Now i am ready and want add my 2 existing laravel projects from an other server. But i always get now the 404 Error from Nginx in browser after its redirect to login page (automatically if i enter the address and port from public folder). Script works great on other server and its only can be an Permission folder error from "`Laravelproject/storage`" or other, i think.

I have tries many things, from cache cleaning and restart the nginx,php and check all folder Permission ,all now 777 ,yes i know its not safe but i get always the "`Permission denied`" error in my nginx `error.log` file.

Here the errors i get always in log file:

```
 [error] 29564#0: *16 directory index of "/var/www/html/project/" is forbidden, client: ::1, server: localhost, request: "GET /project/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/html/project/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/html/project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107

    [error] 28854#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/html/project/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/html/project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
```

The most error is `laravel.log` but its have now 777 Permission .

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 7171 ;
    listen [::]:7171;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html/project/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }



    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

i cant also run the Project with

```
php artisan serve
```

i get this error:

```
  [ErrorException]                                   
  passthru() has been disabled for security reasons
```

But i dont think thats an problem, its just nginx that blocks it now.

Any ideas? I have worked now some months on this project and its very frustrating now.... I have search on google 24 hours now and try all things i have found without results. I using Laravel 5.4. And the server before was apache not nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Solution! Edit this line:

```
 #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

and add

```
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

example:

```
location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
```